# Matplotlib: Adjusting z-levels of errorbars in barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(4)
y1, y2 = [1,2,1,1], [2,3,1,1.5]


pl.bar(x+0.2,y2, width=0.45, color='g')
pl.errorbar(x+0.4,y2,fmt=None, yerr=0.75, ecolor='r', 
            lw=2, capsize=10., mew = 3)

pl.bar(x,y1,width=0.45)
pl.errorbar(x+0.2,y1,fmt=None, yerr=0.5, ecolor='r', 
            lw=2, capsize=10., mew = 3)

pl.savefig('err.png')
```

produces

[image]

I want the errorbars of the green values to be ***covered*** by the blue bars.

I thought adjusting the z-levels of the plots should achieve that (this is why I'm using .bar and .errorbar separately in the first place):

```
pl.bar(x+0.2,y2, width=0.45, color='g', zorder=1)
pl.errorbar(x+0.4,y2,fmt=None, yerr=0.75, ecolor='r', 
            lw=2, capsize=10., mew = 3, zorder=1)

pl.bar(x,y1,width=0.45, zorder=2)
pl.errorbar(x+0.2,y1,fmt=None, yerr=0.5, ecolor='r', 
            lw=2, capsize=10., mew = 3, zorder=2)
```

This gives[image]

I wasn't able to find a combination of zorders that works. How do I properly adjust the z-levels of errorbars in a Matplotlib barchart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to set the z-order of the caplines separately (they are one of the three objects returned by [pylab.errorbar](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar):

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(4)
y1, y2 = [1,2,1,1], [2,3,1,1.5]


pl.bar(x+0.2,y2, width=0.45, color='g', zorder=1)
_, caplines, _ = pl.errorbar(x+0.4,y2,fmt=None, yerr=0.75, ecolor='r', 
            lw=2, capsize=10., mew = 3, zorder=2)

pl.bar(x,y1,width=0.45, zorder=3)
pl.errorbar(x+0.2,y1,fmt=None, yerr=0.5, ecolor='r', 
            lw=2, capsize=10., mew = 3, zorder=4)

for capline in caplines:
    capline.set_zorder(2)

pl.savefig('err.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick. A note that might be of interest: This solution does not work with the old 1.1.1rc version of Matplotlib, but works fine with 1.3.1 upwards.